# Drawing brackets over plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

How would I go about if I wanted to draw brackets over some parts of my plot like this :

[image: brackets over plot]

At the moment I am adding them with powerpoint but I would like to do it entirely in python.

Comment: Other applicable answers: [Annotating ranges of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18386210/7758804) & [How does one insert statistical annotations (stars or p-values)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36578458/7758804)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way to get what you want (or something very close to it) is to use matplotlib's `annotate` function which allows you to customize the arrow function quite extensively (see the [official tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html)). Here is a sample with some made up plot data to show how to use it according to your label requirements:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make some fake data and a sample plot
x = np.arange(1,100)
y = x**2 * 1.0e6
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(x,y)

# Adjust the fontsizes on tick labels for this plot
fs = 14.0
[t.set_fontsize(fs) for t in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()]
[t.set_fontsize(fs) for t in ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels()]
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(fs)

# Here is the label and arrow code of interest
ax.annotate('SDL', xy=(0.5, 0.90), xytext=(0.5, 1.00), xycoords='axes fraction', 
            fontsize=fs*1.5, ha='center', va='bottom',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc='white', color='k'),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-[, widthB=7.0, lengthB=1.5', lw=2.0, color='k'))
```

[image]

The `annotate` function contains the text label you desire as well as arguments for positioning for the arrow (`xy`) and the text itself (`xycoords`) and some general positioning and fontsize commands.

What is probably most of interest are the `bbox` and `arrowprops` arguments. The `bbox` argument draws a square around the label with a white background. The `arrowprops` are more involved--the `arrowstyle` key sets the head of the arrow (a bracket in this case) as well as the width and length of the head. Note that this is all one string under `arrowstyle`. Finally, the linewidth of the arrow is increased slightly.

You might have to adjust `xy`, `xytext`, `widthB`, `lengthB`, and the arrow's `lw` to get everything as you want it.

One thing that's not immediately clear (or at least wasn't to me when I figured this out) was that when `annotate` contains an `arrowstyle` argument, matplotlib uses the [`FancyArrowPatch` properties](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch), but when `arrowstyle` is missing, it uses the [`YAArrow` properties](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.YAArrow). There is obviously more detail (as well as this distinction) noted in the documentation for [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation).

Comment: Something I also found useful is the option: ```annotation_clip=False``` which allows the annotation to occupy space outside of the axes plot.