# How does one insert statistical annotations (stars or p-values)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations

This seems like a trivial question, but I've been searching for a while and can't seem to find an answer. It also seems like something that should be a standard part of these packages.  Does anyone know if there is a standard way to include statistical annotation between distribution plots in seaborn?

For example, between two box or swarmplots?

[image: Example: the yellow distribution is significantly different than the others (by wilcoxon - how can i display that visually?]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A brace / bracket can be plotted direct with [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html), and annotations can be added with [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html).

`seaborn` categorical plots are 0 indexed, whereas box plots, by default, with `matplotlib` and `pandas`, start at `range(1, N+1)`, which can be adjusted with the `positions` parameter.

`seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`, and `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dataframe in long form for seaborn
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# dataframe in wide form for plotting with pandas.DataFrame.plot
df = tips.pivot(columns='day', values='total_bill')

# data as a list of lists for plotting directly with matplotlib (no nan values allowed)
data = [df[c].dropna().tolist() for c in df.columns]
```

### `seaborn`

```py
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, palette="PRGn")

# statistical annotation
x1, x2 = 2, 3   # columns 'Sat' and 'Sun' (first column: 0, see plt.xticks())
y, h, col = tips['total_bill'].max() + 2, 2, 'k'

plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2], [y, y+h, y+h, y], lw=1.5, c=col)
plt.text((x1+x2)*.5, y+h, "ns", ha='center', va='bottom', color=col)

plt.show()
```

[image: box plot annotated]

### `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='box', positions=range(len(df.columns)))

x1, x2 = 2, 3
y, h, col = df.max().max() + 2, 2, 'k'

ax.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2], [y, y+h, y+h, y], lw=1.5, c=col)
ax.text((x1+x2)*.5, y+h, "ns", ha='center', va='bottom', color=col)
```

[image]

### `matplotlib`

```py
plt.boxplot(data, positions=range(len(data)))

x1, x2 = 2, 3

y, h, col = max(map(max, data)) + 2, 2, 'k'

plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2], [y, y+h, y+h, y], lw=1.5, c=col)
plt.text((x1+x2)*.5, y+h, "ns", ha='center', va='bottom', color=col)
```

[image]

---

`tips.head()`

```
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

`df.head()`

```
day  Thur  Fri  Sat    Sun
0     NaN  NaN  NaN  16.99
1     NaN  NaN  NaN  10.34
2     NaN  NaN  NaN  21.01
3     NaN  NaN  NaN  23.68
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  24.59
```

`data`

```
[[27.2, 22.76, 17.29, ..., 20.53, 16.47, 18.78],
 [28.97, 22.49, 5.75, ..., 13.42, 16.27, 10.09],
 [20.65, 17.92, 20.29, ..., 29.03, 27.18, 22.67, 17.82],
 [16.99, 10.34, 21.01, ..., 18.15, 23.1, 15.69]]
```

Answer (score 71):

One may also be interested in adding *several* annotations to different pairs of boxes. In such a case, it might be useful to handle the placement of the different lines and texts in the y-axis automatically. I and other contributors wrote a small function to handle these cases (see [Github repo](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot)), which correctly stacks the lines one on top of each other without overlapping. Annotations can be either inside or outside the plot, and several statistical tests are implemented: Mann-Whitney and t-test (independent and paired). Here is one minimal example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from statannot import add_stat_annotation

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

x = "day"
y = "total_bill"
order = ['Sun', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat']
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, order=order)
add_stat_annotation(ax, data=df, x=x, y=y, order=order,
                    box_pairs=[("Thur", "Fri"), ("Thur", "Sat"), ("Fri", "Sun")],
                    test='Mann-Whitney', text_format='star', loc='outside', verbose=2)
```

[image: example1]

```
x = "day"
y = "total_bill"
hue = "smoker"
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue)
add_stat_annotation(ax, data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue,
                    box_pairs=[(("Thur", "No"), ("Fri", "No")),
                                 (("Sat", "Yes"), ("Sat", "No")),
                                 (("Sun", "No"), ("Thur", "Yes"))
                                ],
                    test='t-test_ind', text_format='full', loc='inside', verbose=2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1))
```

[image: example2]

Comment: The function name is "add_stat_annotation", the one above isn't working. Also you need to define x and y:
    add_stat_annotation(ax, x="day", y="total_bill",df, [("Thur", "Fri"), ("Thur", "Sat"), ("Fri", "Sun")],  test='t-test', order=None, textFormat='full', loc='inside', verbose=2)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer to reflect the changes in the `statannot` package. Note that now it can also be applied to a boxplot with hue categories, as in the second example. Unfortunately, we still need to give the same exact `data`, `x`, `y` and `hue` arguments to the `add_stat_annotation` method than those used to generate the seaborn boxplot.

Comment: boxPairList and textFormat arguments are outdated, should be box_pairs and text_format

Comment: Extremely grateful for this! Can I please ask why you require python3? Can it be used in python2 as well? Thanks.

Comment: The statannot package has only been test for python3, but could be adapted to python2.

Comment: Does this support anova?

Comment: @NelsonGon Not for the moment. Please refer to the github repository for the latest updates on the package functionalities.

Comment: This works so well. Thanks for making this! Beautiful

Comment: Does it support subplot? i have the following error: 



cat = box_plotter.plot_hues is None and boxName or boxName[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.```

Comment: This should be the top answer as its much more automatised and complete than the marked as "correct" answer.

Comment: It would be great if you could get this fully functional for barplots too. As it is, in my own examples and also in your own barplot example in the github repository, the vertical positions of the annotations place themselves as if it was a boxplot, i.e. floating high above the barplot mean value and stretching the y-axis scale. A great tool for boxplots though!

Comment: @cjstevens, Statannot is not actively maintained. You could have a look at a fork of statannot, [statannotations](https://github.com/trevismd/statannotations), which supports barplots gracefully since version 0.3.2, with the exact same API as statannot. The newest (alpha) version has a few more features (and bugfixes), and a different user interface.

Comment: If you don't want to use seaborn, this might be an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180887/10794682