# Adding symbols to some variables in matplotlib bar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I would like to add stars to certain variables in a matplotlib.pyplot bar plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
ind = np.arange(N) # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r')
ax.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,bottom=menMeans, color='b')
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
ax.legend(labels=['Men', 'Women'])
plt.show()
```

Supose I wanted to add stars *** to the top of the bars at G1 and G3.  How could I do this?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Seaborn - How to add significance bars and asterisks to boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707406/python-seaborn-how-to-add-significance-bars-and-asterisks-to-boxplots)

Comment: For example, a three star rating for G1 can be handled by.`ax.text(x=0, y=45, s='***', ha='center', font=dict(size=20))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by placing the `***` with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) . First calculate, the bar heights by summing both `meanMeans` and `womenMeans`, then pass the bar as `x` and the height as `y`.

```py
# Add *** to G1 and G3
bar_heights = [mm + wm for mm, wm in zip(menMeans, womenMeans)]
ax.text(x=0, y=bar_heights[0]+1, s="***", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=15)
ax.text(x=2, y=bar_heights[2]+1, s="***", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]