# Add statistically significant difference between bars to plotnine plot (ggpubr equivalent)

Tags: python, ggplot2, ggpubr, significance, plotnine

In many plots one wants to highlight the statistical significance of an observed difference between some results. This task can be done in R using the `ggpubr()` or the `geom.signif()` extension.

An example of what I mean is here (see horizontal bars with stars):
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40496-8/figures/1

I am generating the exact same plot as shown in the figure, but my workflow is python-based and it would annoy me to go through R just for this. I would like to obtain something like what is suggested in this other thread for R, but in python plotnine:
[Put stars on ggplot barplots and boxplots - to indicate the level of significance (p-value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084566/put-stars-on-ggplot-barplots-and-boxplots-to-indicate-the-level-of-significanc)

As far as I could find, there is no way of getting this type of statistical representation with plotnine. Do you have workarounds or suggestions? Am I missing it from the plotnine API?

Answer (score 2):

Came here in search of the same thing, as plotnine's API is missing an equivalent for ggpubr's stat_compare_means (plotnine is an implementation of ggplot2, so perhaps it is not surprising the archives are incomplete).

However, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578458/how-does-one-insert-statistical-annotations-stars-or-p-values-into-matplotlib/37518947#37518947) thread, I found another library named [statannot](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot) which seems to do just that.